# Error in ggplotly: attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I would like to produce interactive ggplot graph using the function `ggplotly`

Here is my code:

```
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds),1000),]

p <- ggplot(data = d,aes(x=carat,y=price))+
  geom_point(aes(text=paste("Clarity:",clarity)),size = 4)+
  geom_smooth(aes(color = cut,fill=cut))+facet_wrap(~cut)

gg <- ggplotly(p)
```

However, the error shows up as after the last codeg`gplotly(p)`:

> Error in gg2list(p, width = width, height = height, tooltip = tooltip,
>   :    attempt to apply non-function

Any idea to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plotly_build` instead. The following code works on my pc:

```
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds),1000),]

p <- ggplot(data = d,aes(x=carat,y=price))+
  geom_point(aes(text=paste("Clarity:",clarity)),size = 4)+
  geom_smooth(aes(color = cut,fill=cut))+facet_wrap(~cut)


gg <- plotly_build(p)
print(gg)
```

Comment: What is your package versions? I am running plotly_4.6.0    and ggplot2_2.2.1 on a windows 7 machine. Try running  `sessionInfo()` on rstudio/r console and update package if necessary.

Comment: Dear friend, it's not necessary to use `plotly_build(p)`, `ggplotly(p)` works after updating all the packages. What should be mentioned is that it's recommended to update ggplot2 using `install_github("hadley/ggplot2")`

Comment: That's interesting. As far as I remember, I installed ggplot from cran not github. `ggplotly` was not working for me, but `plotly_build` did. The versioning issues are really crappy sometimes :(